# How long does Intuit's Security Review take from start to finish to review QuickBooks Online (QBO) app?

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to budget my time wisely but have not had a lot of details on the Security Review that Intuit performs on applications before publication.  I found an article on their blog that talks about pre-paring for it.

[The "Security Review": What to Expect](http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/01/the-security-review-what-to-expect.html)

and then there is their [Complete the Security Review](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0040_Publishing_Your_App/0030_Passing_the_Security_Review) section on their website.  However I have not been able to find anything on the expected timeline to complete.  One person mentioned on their v3 webinar that his took 3 months to complete, but is this the norm?

Thanks for any help in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not take months to complete, normally it takes 1-2 weeks assuming you follow the guidelines and prepare for the reviews accordingly. Obviously if there are security vulnerabilities found in your app it could take time to resolve so 1-2 weeks is an average and assuming you are able to resolve issues as soon as possible.

Also, if you follow the info here it will speed up the process
https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0040_Publishing_Your_App

regards, 
Jarred

Comment: Thank you, I will pass this information along to the appropriate channels in my company for time management and review preparation.